# Different Estimates but same Out-of-sample predictive accuracy

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, accuracy, out-of-sample

I have two different models that give me different estimates on my data. The difference is not huge, but one model significantly shrinks the estimates towards zero.

However, when I run leave-one-out out-of-sample predictive accuracy, the models perform roughly the same. Furthermore, when I calculate mean absolute error for some synthetic data, one of the model significantly outperforms the other.

What are the possible reasons why the two models have similar out-of-sample predictive accuracy despite giving different estimates for your data?